# False positive spam GMAIL sending mail with PHPMailer

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

I'm sending emails using PHPMailer. Everything is ok but when I have GMAIL recipients my message is considered SPAM.

This is the header of the message:

```
Delivered-To: GMAIL RECIPIENT
Received: by 2002:a17:90a:930c:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id p12csp902239pjo; 
Fri,3 May 2019 10:26:50 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source:
APXvYqzaVDtu9MY1IwDwFVItDao6xtvrlbFEFLUHKH3gBC6rLdqqQ6hkgOh42NEcioBFEtrAJuKo
X-Received: by 2002:adf:fd04:: with SMTP id e4mr8087537wrr.145.1556904410309;
Fri, 03 May 2019 10:26:50 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1556904410; cv=none;
    d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
    b=zIxuikro8ixhsX4eZJNRM1wqEcEvrLaLSW7h5UzLbFGCYfy4MstVjtkRXEAYH3MdMB
     RRFxSLU5/4gY0qpAwNUA6g1qmCyif4JAPrsxPrFs4PYotcvkEAQcpSan5kw4NXyttM5T
     SvFykeMFYhtoUksc3QAwzVIm2OK0beYvWf4vGNF7Y4HHNwzvTxzSE1pwn0xkq46VQeqa
     /BX6Fbjqcxje6oG3k5ugxhpe3p3acShmI44yPrTxNla99+wyTofQjZmJyhb2Gj8sNhUO
     Ef2CkMlQCFgKBsrvAk/or+L19RX+EkY122duXUhpscP+dYxbkAjfR1aJVcRMTY6OdODB
     xajQ==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com
s=arc-20160816;
    h=mime-version:message-id:subject:from:to:date:dkim-signature;
    bh=PIhYyd0+ywcPkuj0Hoe6VNtKZaS57XHJj9uvkHRR28Q=;
    b=Vb1UyR8CCpIGMcGL/dqNuJgZGEVGY5AVwcn+WmYj42pfCekCemfcUTejSH0bgoXJMQ
     5YkMlSAKjTgTRPg3AYKs198bN2hIzWLS3iO6yPqeqcWvSxSexGDuXXahgOK0Ha2dvEGp
     G5HIe5s+TA4vZ6a2ZXnzSFNEW8yLZQd64XOpBrssuVL9A9up8Mr/liXzEdxE4bSjvRVE
     Jjlt4UWM6zMwV6jbhK2RSNqJmaYRo84PACNBf4btLrdQ8VbHUm6Y5K71eD1159JWjnwW
     SixO3XoeLeTvuXdYNlBRZsa+bvLKMMvZ4OKJpaOJ3eVuzJXnE5q0D4txeIlX3QeIL3XK
     ARMg==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@domain.it header.s=mail header.b=qscWpy85;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of services@domain.it designates IP as
permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=services@domain.it
Return-Path: <services@domain.it>
Received: from mailout.multiwire.net (mailout.multiwire.net. [IP])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id v4si1624284wmj.132.2019.05.03.10.26.50
    for <GMAIL RECIPIENT>
    (version=TLS1_1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA bits=128/128);
    Fri, 03 May 2019 10:26:50 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of services@domain.it designates IP
as permitted sender) client-ip=IP;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@domain.it header.s=mail header.b=qscWpy85;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of services@domain.it designates IP as
permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=services@domain.it
X-Spam-Status: No, hits=0.1 required=4.0 tests=AWL: 0.161, HTML_MESSAGE:
0.001, TOTAL_SCORE: 0.162,autolearn=ham
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Footer: bWFpbG91dC5tdWx0aXdpcmUubmV0
Received: from mail.multiwire.net ([10.100.1.20]) (authenticated user
mail@mailout.multiwire.net) by mailout.multiwire.net with ESMTPSA (using
TLSv1.1 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256 bits)) for GMAIL RECIPIENT;
Fri, 3 May 2019 19:31:33 +0200
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=coalvi.it; s=mail;
h=from:subject:date:message-id:to:mime-version:content-type
bh=PIhYyd0+ywcPkuj0Hoe6VNtKZaS57XHJj9uvkHRR28Q=; 
b=qscWpy85HxbaA6Q6WOKlaaYwokzQW/jNn10WnXIq9kpnOAYCaUwCaCYUGjbo
/c3GLRGA07vRLGh1k

cHLKN0u7Abs0yPDnlOZZ0ApSflDudu+XVSSBFRbiB9ENbu8U+WaDQFibhhdSmmpyPnNo8Y0tfIkhtR
 3KvDsSmAFtzKmWPUR0uKxbHZTnPcLrLCJErzdrJstRYLSupHyDyauHFXs2pA28W1KR2EWESMLePcBF
 BptTQ7ONz5NMsxUlr1VtTKSbrwd3dYDnzXicKpR0bTCcJIKb3bzZ2wHapnuwTdGUnxuvEVVXEnNBff
 z/2zNcp5O8BUOxuh7m7fKq194gn5TMg==
X-Footer: Y29hbHZpLml0
Received: from www.domain.it ([SERVER IP]) (authenticated user 
services@domain.it) by mail.multiwire.net with ESMTPSA (using TLSv1.2 with 
cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256 bits)) for GMAIL RECIPIENT; Fri, 3
May 2019 19:26:48 +0200
Date: Fri, 3 May 2019 19:26:57 +0200
Return-Path: services@domain.it
To: "gmail recipient" <gmail address>
From: Services <services@domain.it>
Subject: Subject
Message-ID: <8f783abffef8e00a08ce8bb63d2cda2d@www.domain.it>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.1 (phpmailer.sourceforge.net)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
boundary="b1_8f783abffef8e00a08ce8bb63d2cda2d"

--b1_8f783abffef8e00a08ce8bb63d2cda2d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset = "iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

TEXT


--b1_8f783abffef8e00a08ce8bb63d2cda2d
Content-Type: text/html; charset = "iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

TEXT



--b1_8f783abffef8e00a08ce8bb63d2cda2d--
```

I had an attachment (a .zip file) but removing it I had the same problem.
I also tried removing part of the text to avoid using some wrong content. 
I read that some problems could be generated by links inside text but I have no links.
So, I don't find why my message is classified SPAM.
I made a lot of research on the Internet and found many people telling that X-Spam-Status header should be YES with a higher score than I have to consider a SPAM.

Why is my message declared as SPAM?

Comment: DID u config the SPF and DKIM?

Comment: IME, this is just business as usual for gmail's inept spam filter. The headers say that your message is not spam, and it passes SPF and DKIM checks, but gmail puts it in the spam folder anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail usually blocks messages if the sender domain address is different than mail server. Take a look at theese lines:

```
from www.domain.it ([SERVER IP]) (authenticated user 
services@domain.it) by mail.multiwire.net
```

Comment: That's unlikely to be a cause. This situation is covered by DMARC alignment, which in this case gmail says it's happy with. Also bear in mind that messages sent *from* gmail don't do this either.

Comment: any solutions for this case?